# How to access OwnCloud files from web interface to filesystem?

Tags: centos

We have an OwnCloud server. Files uploaded via the HTTPS interface can be retrieved on the filesystem in the path

```
/var/www/html/owncloud_content/our_username/path/to/files
```

However, these files are encrypted. How can we retrieve the original files?

We have full administrative access on the OwnCloud app and root access on the Linux server (CentOS 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dectyption can be done via the `occ` command. Single user mode needs to be activated:

```
sudo -u www-data ./occ maintenance:singleuser --on
sudo -u www-data ./occ encryption:decrypt-all [username]
```

Assumption being encryption via master key.

[Reference](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/configuration/files/encryption/encryption_configuration.html#decrypt-master-key-encryption)

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution, but it would affect the whole server, which is what we're trying to avoid.

Comment: You may apply it to a specific user only by providing the username.